# Is there $\varphi$-invariant measure with full support

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

It is known that a  group action $\varphi:G\times X\to X$ on the compact metric space $X$ has a $\varphi$- invariant Borel probability measure on $X$ if and only if $G$ is amenable. Note that the group $G$ is  amenable, if there is a sequence of finite sets $\{F_n\}_{n=0}^\infty\subseteq G$ such that

\begin{equation*}
\lim _{n\to \infty}\frac{|gF_n\Delta F_n|}{|F_n|}=0, \forall g\in G
\end{equation*}

In my research I need to work with a measure $\mu$ that is $\varphi$-invariant and $supp(\mu)=X$. What conditions imply it? Please help to know it.